# Probabilities of nested intervals tending to single point

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Say I have a probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ over $\mathbb{R}$ without any atoms, by which I mean $\mathbb{P}(\{x\}) = 0 \; \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$. Does it follow that a sequence of nested intervals tending to a point will have probabilities which tend to 0?

For instance, does it follow that $\mathbb{P}([x - \frac1n, x + \frac1n]) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$? The limit itself should exist, by monotone convergence, but it's not clear to me why it would need to be 0 (if this is indeed true). I'm looking for a result about how probability measures interact with infinite intersections/chains of sets, or a counter-example.

Answer (score 1):

The result you are looking is known as "continuity of the probability measure" and it can be found (i guess) in every introductory probability textbook. This says that whenever you have a decreasing (there is also a corresponding result for increasing sequences) sequence of measurable sets $A_n$, then $$\mathbb{P}\bigl(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\bigr)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\mathbb{P}(A_n)$$

In your case the $A_n's$ are the intervals $[x-\frac{1}{n},x+\frac{1}{n}]$. Here, its easy to check that $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[x-\frac{1}{n},x+\frac{1}{n}]=\{x\}$. Which means that
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\mathbb{P}([x-\frac{1}{n},x+\frac{1}{n}])=\mathbb{P}(\{x\})$$

If you are dealing with a measure with no atoms, then $\mathbb{P}(\{x\})=0$.